# How to install Jar (java) to NVIDIA-Docker image or NVIDIA-Docker dependencies to Java image?

Tags: java, docker, docker-image, nvidia-docker, dockerfile-maven-plugin

I have to bundle up my system using Docker. But my system uses Java (JAR file to run) and python with PyTorch. I initially tried to use **openjdk:buster** base Docker image and then installed python3 on top of it. So both JAR and PyTorch worked, but PyTorch is only CPU supportive. But now I have to speed-up my PyTorch code using GPU, and for that I need NVIDIA-Cuda. In a separate Docker, I found **nvidia/cuda:10.2-base-ubuntu18.04** works for my PyTorch. But this Docker can't run JAR file.

So I am stuck in combining these 2. I either want to

1. install NVIDIA-Cuda dependencies to openjdk Docker base image
2. install openjdk (**openjdk-14**) dependencies to NVIDIA-Cuda Docker base image

Anyone has any suggestions on how I can do that or any alternative hacks ?

Answer (score 3):

You can have a single image, instead of two by creating your own docker image that uses the nvidia image, and install java on it.  I.e. have a Dockerfile as below

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-base-ubuntu18.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install openjdk-14-jdk

COPY <your jar file> <a path>
CMD [ "java" "other java flags/args>" "-jar" "<path to your jar file>"]
```

run `docker build` on that Dockerfile, and `docker run` as you normally would, and your java code should have access to NVIDIA-Cuda.  (Also note, some prefer ENTRYPOINT to CMD)